# pdb.set_trace() equivalent in web browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

While debugging python application, I normally use pdb / ipdb's set_trace() function to programmatically invoke breakpoint.

I was thinking whether similar things are possible in web browser's javascript. I'm pretty sure that if they exist, it's some browser-specific extensions to Firebug / Chrome / IE, but I couldn't find any information about them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried inserting the [`debugger` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bwt76sk(VS.94).aspx)? It will be treated as a breakpoint if you have a JS debugger like Firebug running.

Comment: but for nodejs, on the server side, do we have any such tool?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar you will need to run node with the `--inspect` option. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/, but yeah it works!